# Input Complex values into python 2.x or higher version

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

In python, how to input Complex values which have been declared as Complex.

I tried to input `5+j6`, the program terminated stating that `j6 not defined`.

Comment: Improved formatting to get a better reading and focus the relevant part.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3 you need to do three things:

1. Place the imaginary unit `j` after the imaginary part `6` (no blank spaces in between).
2. Remove the all the blank spaces (if any) around the `+` operator.
3. Convert your input - which is of type `str` - into a complex number through the built-in function `complex()`.

Demo:

```
>>> s = input('Enter complex number: ')
Enter complex number: 5+6j
>>> print(type(s))
<class 'str'>
>>> z = complex(s)
>>> print(z)
(5+6j)
>>> print(type(z))
<class 'complex'>
```

In Python 2 you can skip steps 2 and 3:

```
>>> z = input('Enter complex number: ')
Enter complex number: 5 + 6j
>>> print z
(5+6j)
>>> print type(z) 
<class 'complex'>
```